# Multilple file upload not working in magento2.3.0?

Tags: magento2, admin, file-upload

I am not able to upload multiple files in magento2.3.0?

Here is my code:

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'commercial_pic',
            'file',
            [
                'name' => 'commercial_pic',
                'data-form-part' => $this->getData('target_form'),
                'label' => __('Commercial Doc'),
                'title' => __('Commercial Doc'),
                'multiple'=> 'multiple',
                'value' => $partner['commercial_pic'],
                'after_element_html' => '<label style="width:100%;">
                    Allowed File Type : [jpg, jpeg, gif, png]
                </label>
                <img style="margin:5px 0;width:250px;"
                src="'.$this->getBaseUrl().'pub/media/avatar/customer/commercial/'.$partner['commercial_pic'].'"
                />',
            ]
        );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to check its file size also. May be your file size exceed its limit.

Comment: I have inspect the particular field, there itself not showing multiple